# Carregar "php.ini" especifico para um sub-domínio

Tags: php, linux, htaccess, fastcgi

Para carregar um `php.ini` personalizado para um sub-domínio, apliquei no `.htaccess` na raiz do sub-domínio em questão o seguinte código:

```
AddHandler php5-fastcgi .php
Action php5-fastcgi /cgi-bin/php.fcgi
```

<sup>O ficheiro só tem estas duas linhas.</sup>

O mesmo carrega as definições em condições e de forma independente do domínio principal, que consigo ver através do [**`phpinfo()`**](http://pt1.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.phpinfo.php).

## Problema

Com a linha em cima presente no `.htaccess`, deixo de conseguir aceder ao sub-domínio, só conseguindo aceder ao mesmo através do domínio principal seguido da pasta onde se encontra o sub-domínio:

Acesso pretendido:

```
http://sub.dominio.com/
```

Acesso que funciona com as directivas em cima:

```
http://www.dominio.com/sub/
```

<sup>**Nota:**

No `htaccess` na raiz do domínio principal existem diversas directivas para uso do `mod_rewrite.c`, `mod_deflate.c`, `Options`, `IndexIgnore`, `Header`, as quais se relevantes para o problema poderei adicionar aqui.</sup>

## Pergunta

O que falta ou estou a fazer de errado para perder o acesso directo via sub-domínio quando tenho as duas linhas no `.htaccess` do mesmo?

Answer (score 1):

Use a diretiva `PHPINIDir` na configuração de virtual host do site para o qual você quer especificar um `php.ini` personalizado.

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    PHPINIDir /var/www/web1
</VirtualHost>
```